# .net 3.5 simple win application error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, installation

I have a .net win app that seems to work for all our of test machines but the client is getting this error after installation. So the install seems to be working but the app running creates an issue.

The exception unknown software exception (0xc06d007e) occured in the application at location 0xfd96aa7d

Any ideas how to fix or troubleshoot without going back to the customer for techie debug

Comment: Check you Reference Dependencies..Did you use Setup and Deployment for the Setup installation..And install .net framework 3.5 to your clients?

Comment: Do you have the option to provide your customer with debug builds and the pdb files? If so providing the client with them will most likely provide more information as to where (line number) the exception is occurring. @Crimsonland is probably correct in that some assemblies seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Idea for troubleshooting - there may be an entry in Administrative Tools->Event Viewer (look inside Windows Logs->Application) that could help you narrow down the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that some of the resources where being blocked by the end user downloading from the web. FTP solved it